# Overcoming retrieving content from rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, web-scraping

I was able to retrieve rss by adding a /feed for most of the wordpress blog. Like one of the example is https://www.techinasia.com/feed.

But I found that many blogs/sites when I added a /feed in the end it will show feedburner thingy. Like hongkiat.com/blog/feed it will become http://feeds2.feedburner.com/24thfloor. How to overcome this? develop 2 version of code?

Comment: Clarify your question, add some code, add error codes etc.

Comment: @Ziumin DO u have any idea?

Comment: U didn't provided any code or error codes. U just said that **some** script failed to parse relocated feeds. It's not enoght to give any advice or an answer

Comment: @Ziumin do my question need code? you read again please.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to the server that setup their /feed to use feedburner, you won't be able to change anything on your end.

The concept is pretty simple:

1. you have a /feed that gives you the feed of the website as expected
2. you have a small setup in Apache (or equivalent HTTP server) to tell to redirect the user if he's not a feedburner server; so the feedburner can read the /feed data directly, anyone else can't.

However, I don't see why you think this is a problem. The data you get is exactly the same. Only you get an intermediate 301 when retrieving the data using the original /feed path.

There is same examples on this website on that's achieved (.htaccess or a PHP snippet):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_FeedBurner

If the test used by the server with the /feed only checks the User Agent name, then you could simulate being feedburner. But again, you will have much more chance to connect and read the data using feedburner (because that's owned by Google and they have the horse power to send you the content of the feed without an inch of a problem.)

Comment: Hi thanks Alex! Can u take a look on this too ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699805/xml-enclosure-url-image-quality

Comment: Hum... if the goal is just to find feeds, do not use `/feed` because you'll miss a lot of feeds! RSS has a discovery protocol which links feeds from HTML documents: look for <link> elements in the <head> section.