# get URL from XML enclosure

Tags: php, xml, rss

http://paultan.org/feed/

In above feed I can get the img ur like http://s2.paultan.org/image/2014/12/Theo-top-10-fave-renders-108x108.jpg

but in feedly.com I'm seeing other link of image, which have bigger size. I wonder how feedly can retrieve the 's content since it's not in the feed's DOM.

Comment: Do you have a URL to the feedly.com copy? Or do you have to have an account there?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I sign in of course.

Answer (score 0):

Would this link represent the large image that you see?

http://s1.paultan.org/image/2014/12/top-10-posts.jpg

feedly.com may be reading the destination page once and save it in their database. From the header you have a Facebook entry as follow:

```
<meta content="http://s1.paultan.org/image/2014/12/top-10-posts.jpg"
      property="og:image">
```

which feedly.com would be using to present the image. This, of course, means a lot more bandwidth used in order to be able to display such information. They may also limit it to websites that have such headers (so they test once or twice, if the website does not offer a link like the `og:image`, they stop testing that website altogether, at least for a while...)

Comment: so feedly is not scrapping their rss?

Comment: btw, I'm seeing this image http://s2.paultan.org/image/2014/12/Theo-top-10-fave-renders.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I checked the wrong page... the feed changes everyday... The correct page has this path: `<meta content="http://s1.paultan.org/image/2014/12/Theo-top-10-fave-renders.jpg" property="og:image">`. The 's1' or 's2' difference is certainly used to make it easier to handle heavy loads.

Comment: so feedly is not scrapping rss right? is it hard to develop an engine like theirs? the accuracy is so high, nice job to their team.

Comment: It's more than just scrapping the RSS file. But it certainly not hard to do. Just a little extension really.

Comment: But I don't even know where to begin. I scrapped DOM before but this time it's different.