# Get img url from enclosure in rss feed

Tags: php, rss

i have a little problem.
I have the following code on my site to post some news from a rss file:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->load('http://rt.com/rss/');
$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 3;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}?>
```

I want also to get the image link from the rss file that looks like:

> enclosure url="IMG URL" length="" type=""

but i can't get it to work, i tried some examples found here, my php knowledge it's not so good.
Any ideeas how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: try like this: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: [so what else have you tried so far?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27699805/get-url-from-xml-enclosure)

Comment: Amit, i tried to do a similar code for enclosure like is for title, desc, link and date but after that i found i should use something like enclosure['url']. Then i got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php to see how to fetch an attribute from a DOMElement. In this case you could use `$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')` to get the image URL. You could also try using SimpleXMLElement (see PHP documentation) which is a bit easier to use than DOMDocument (but as a trade-off also has less functionality).

Some other pointers, if you are only appending one element to an array, instead of using `array_push` use the syntax `$array[] = $element`. `$array[]` is a language construct which is more efficient than an internal function like `array_push`. Also instead of using `str_replace` to replace `&` with `&amp;`, use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities`, it's safer and also replaces other characters that you don't want in your HTML like `<` and `>`.

Comment: But where to put that code exactly? I tried after the $item = array () but i get the same image for every post.

Comment: Put `'img' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')` in the `foreach` loop, and in your `for` loop use `$img = $feed[$x]['img']`. If you get the same image have you check if that's because the img in the rss is always the same? I also noticed that in the description there's also an <img> tag embedded.

Comment: I just did like you said and it works. Thank you again!